# What is the Numpad 5 name for pynput?

Tags: python, pynput

I am trying to make a program that flies in flight simulator for me.  but for some reason all of the numpad keys work with the program except for the number 5. I print out the names of each key and when I click the 5 it says <12>. But when I try it out on flight simulator it makes the view of the game look face down instead of stead out the plane.

Comment: Is numlock on? The `5` isn't actually labeled as anything when numlock is off on most keyboards, so it can show up on the software side as some pretty bizarre things. Trying it now on my keyboard, with numlock off it looks like `5` is something called `<kp-begin>`

Comment: Numlock is off. when numlock is on it shows up as something else. but when numlock is off it comes up as <12>